# Kaminari and extra params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I've looked around and I can't find anything close to answer for this. I think it's a pretty unique edge case though so I'm not surprised.

I have an index page where I'm showing all the leads, but I have 3 separate ways of showing it: unreviewed, reviewed, all. To accomplish this I use the current_page? helper, add: ?unreviewed=true to the url.

This worked no problem by itself, when I added in kaminari for pagination the page params seems to mess this up and make it so the current_page? cant read the extra params.

How can I fix this, or is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

This is using Rails 4 and Kaminari 0.15.1

Controller:

```
def index
    @leads = Lead.order(:id).page params[:page]
    @reviewed_leads = Lead.where(reviewed: true).order(:id).page params[:page]
    @unreviewed_leads = Lead.where(reviewed: nil).order(:id).page params[:page]
    current_page_no = Lead.page
end
```

index.html.erb

```
         <tr>
                <td colspan="7" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="pagination pagination-table">

                        <% if current_page?(controller: 'leads', action: 'index', unreviewed: 'true') %>
                        <%= paginate @unreviewed_leads %>
                        <% elsif current_page?(controller: 'leads', action: 'index', reviewed: 'true') %>
                        <%= paginate @reviewed_leads %>
                        <% else %>
                        <%= paginate @leads %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

It worked when the URL looked like:

```
/closingloop/leads?unreviewed=true
```

with it like this, the current_page isn't reading it right and it's always showing the @leads instance variable

```
/closingloop/leads?page=2&unreviewed=true
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm going to continue trying things. Will update with what I find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller action to

```
def index
  @leads = Lead.where(reviewed: params[:reviewed]).order(:id).page(params[:page])
end
```

Then in your view, you don't have to check for the current page, just make sure that you're passing the value of `params[:reviewed]`

```
<%= paginate @leads, params: { reviewed: params[:reviewed] } %>
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work for showing mixed leads.  This can be achieved by creating a scope

```
# lead model

def self.filter_by_reviewed_status(status)
  case status
  when nil     then scoped
  when 'true'  then where(reviewed: true)
  when 'false' then where(reviewed: false)
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, use this in getting the leads

```
@leads = Lead
  .filter_by_reviewed_status(params[:reviewed])
  .order(:id)
  .page(params[:page])
```

Be sure to set `params[:reviewed]` to either true, false or nil (not pass at all) in links to get the `leads` you need

Comment: This is definitely on the right path. I'm just a bit confused. This works great for showing the unreviewed calls and paginating correctly, but it doesn't seem to work for showing reviewed call or all of them mixed together?

Comment: ah that is right. if you want to show mixed, you'll have to add some logic.  i'll update the answer.

Comment: Great. I'll keep checking back for when your answer changes. Appreciate it!